# Can't install monero GUI, linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

So I have to download, extract and double-click monero-wallet-gui

Okay but it just sais "there is no app installed for shared library files"

How do I run that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monero package is in Ubuntu's 18.10 universe repositories [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/monero) (and [Debian's stretch-backports, buster & sid](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=monero&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)) so assuming you're using Ubuntu 18.10, or Debian stretch, buster, or sid, you should just have to install the package with `apt` (or a front-end like Synaptic)

```
apt-get install monero
```

Then apt will take care of all the required dependencies (and other details you probably don't want to bother with, apt is light years better than searching for, downloading, and struggling to install & run programs).